# Key icon in notification bar lg aristo

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

Sreen shot of home screen with notification bar

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? You did not by any accident confuse us with Imgur?

Answer (score 2):

That indicates you are using VPN to connect to Internet

Either you installed a VPN or a firewall / ad-blocker app that uses VPN (I see you are using Orbot, that could be it)

Comment: I wonder how you guessed what OP wanted to ask. If it was a question at all. To me the "question" rather looks like OP confused us with Imgur :)

Comment: @izzy: Got your point. It seemed to me that he wanted to know what the icon was and didn't know how to upload (not unusual to see links ). That said, there is no question explicitly asked (which I missed) . If you decide to close the question , will delete my answer, no problems with that :)

Comment: Nah. My guess is you figured it correctly. I did not – until I saw your answer :)